# Citations and reference list not working with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

The following code does not format the citation and reference. The final PDF contains the sentence
Let’s cite Mittlebach mittelbach2004.
I am using the latest version of MikTeX, which I (re)installed. I included two error messages I get after the code.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{mittelbach2004,
    title={The \LaTeX Companion},
    author={Mittelbach, Frank and Goossens, Michel},
    year={2004},
    publisher={Addison-Wesley Publishing Company},
    address={Reading (MA):}
  }
\end{filecontents}
%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
%
\begin{document}
Let's cite Mittlebach \cite{mittelbach2004}.
\printbibliography
%
\end{document}
```

Error messages:

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'mittelbach2004' on page 1 undefined on input line 18.


LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 19.
```

Comment: The code produces the expected output for me when compiled with LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX. Did you run Biber on your document? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 explains what Biber does and why you need to run it (the answer mainly talks about BibTeX, but there is a note explaining that the big picture also applies for Biber.) If you are using an editor to run commands for you, have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864.

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but you should generally not include leading or trailing punctuation in fields in the `.bib` file. Don't say `address={Reading (MA):}`, say `address={Reading (MA)},`. The style you are currently using automatically adds a colon after the `location`/`address`. If you want to use a style that normally does not add a colon there, it is normally possible to modify it to do so,